# Get value of an element by javascript in awesomium c#

Tags: javascript, c#, awesomium

I need to get value of an element by javascript in awesomium and i tried this:

```
dynamic ch = (JSObject)br.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult
             ("document.getElementById('ltrl').value");
```

or

```
JSObject ch = br.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult
             ("document.getElementById('ltrl').value");
```

but ch is always null 
how can i get that value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

elegant method from Awesomium examples:

```
JSObject ch = br.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("document");
dynamic document = (JSObject)ch ;
if (document == null) return false;
using (document)
{
   document.getElementById('ltrl').value;
}
```